# dpcc code for fpga emulation using jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, hough-transform, intel-fpga, intel-oneapi

I was performing emulation of hough transform for FPGA's on Jupyterlab but then all i had to do was run the cells:

I get the following error ->

### u196294 is performing Hough Transform compilation emulation notebook.

icpx: warning: use of 'dpcpp' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'icpx -fsycl' [-Wdeprecated]
src/original/hough_transform.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'CL/sycl/INTEL/fpga_extensions.hpp' file not found
#include <CL/sycl/INTEL/fpga_extensions.hpp>   //try this and prev
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/bin/bash: bin/hough_transform.emu: No such file or directory

I am not sure how to solve this. I am unable to find the header files that they are supposed to include. I cant even find the parent directory which is supposed to be 'CL'.

Has anyone done fpga emulation using jupyterLabs and gone through the same problem?
i am eagerly looking for help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make the following changes in the code and it will work perfectly, try to ignore the warnings if you get any.

In the hough_transform.cpp please make the below changes -

1. In line 9 change from

   #include <CL/sycl/INTEL/fpga_extensions.hpp>

to

```
#include <sycl/ext/intel/fpga_extensions.hpp>
```

2. In line 72 change from

   sycl::INTEL::fpga_emulator_selector device_selector

to

```
sycl::ext::intel::fpga_emulator_selector device_selector
```

3. In line 76 change from

   sycl::INTEL::fpga_selector device_selector

to

```
sycl::ext::intel::fpga_selector device_selector
```

In hough_transform_kernel.hpp please make the below changes -

1. In line 9 change from

   #include <CL/sycl/INTEL/fpga_extensions.hpp>

to

```
#include <sycl/ext/intel/fpga_extensions.hpp>
```

2. In line 30 change from

   INTEL::fpga_emulator_selector device_selector

to

```
intel::fpga_emulator_selector device_selector
```

3. In line 32 change from

   INTEL::fpga_selector device_selector

to

```
intel::fpga_selector device_selector
```

And you are getting the error " cannot create directory 'bin': file exists " because there might be a directory named bin already present in that path.

You need to delete it and re-run the cells again and it should work without any errors like the screenshot given below.

[image]